# Filter function can not filter percentages

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function to SUM every amount that has a 4% of taxes and it does work if the filter is a string but not with numbers. Is there a way to make it work with numbers?

=SUMA(FILTER(O7:O50; REGEXMATCH(N7:N50; U29)))

If I use the same function to SUM "fijo" or "variable", it does work, but not with percentages.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: REGEXMATCH is best for text, you can just try to equal the values:

```
=SUMA(FILTER(O7:O50; N7:N50 = U29))
```